# My htaccess file works but is not rewriting

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running a local website on Xampp for Windows (Windows 10, x64) that I will upload on my server as soon as ready.

I'm trying to hide .php extensions from URL with the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

I don't have any knowledge in htaccess files so please correct this code if it's wrong.

I know .htaccess file is working 'cause I put garbage on it and the website stopped working. I also know I don't need .htaccess file since I have access to main server config, but don't have an idea where to put the code above.

I have this on httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

And

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

All I want is my structure to look like: `www.mysite.com/products` instead of `www.mysite.com/products.php`

Comment: have you put the .htaccess file in the document root i.e. www.mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

if your htaccess is working then put this code inside it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: put this htaccess in directory where you want to remove .php extension try this on seperate test project and then tell me what is the error.

Comment: It's already in the directory where I want to remove .php extension; No errors are shown, but doesn't remove the extension

Comment: you are accessing your file `www.mysite.com/products` like this? and reverse any other update you did on httpd.conf.

Comment: It works when I access through `www.mysite.com/products` but it also works when I access through `www.mysite.com/products.php`. Is there anyway to don't allow this?

Comment: Also it would be better if I could just redirect someone to `www.mysite.com/products` when trying to access `www.mysite.com/products.php`

Comment: for redirection part you can do that!

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear, what I meant was: when someone access `www.mysite.com/products.php` htaccess change the url to `www.mysite.com/products`